# HTML Component not rendering in electron react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, electron

The TitleBar from Component.js is not rendering as html in my electron app, I get no errors and have confirmed the file paths.

Component.js,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class TitleBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div id="TitleBar">
                <button id="minButton">_</button>
                <button id="maxButton">[]</button>
                <button id="exitButton">X</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div id="NavBar">
                <button id="homeButton">Home</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Index.js,

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TitleBar from "./Components.js";

console.log('intro');
ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

index.html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DevFlow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="app"></main>
    <script defer type="text/babel" src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the command "npm start" the application comes up, however there is no component within the  tags. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I will also include my Main.js although I don't think it would be necessary to diagnose my issue. Thanks

[image]

Main.js,

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
    frame: false
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: I think maybe my problem lies with the reference to the index.js. When I remove the type="text/babel" I get errors where "import is outside of module" which can be resolved by changing type="module" but then I get an unexpected < character error. **It would seem that the reference from the html cannot interpret JSX**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<base href="/">` at the top of your index.html file.

Comment: Added <base href="./">, and changed src="./index.js" to src="index.js". still not rendering.

Comment: @KyleBatchelor just only change base href as mentioned in the answer. dont use ./

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add babel browser script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DevFlow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="app"></main>
    <script defer type="text/babel" src="./index.js" data-type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue:

the index.js file cannot be read by the browser interpreter because it needs to be compiled into vanilla JS.

Which I will be attempting to do with webpack

Comment: I have a template that uses React that you can start with if you'd like to know how to configure webpack: https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template